# Notification Sound and Badge don't work

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, swift2

I created a remote push notification, the notification works very well, but sound and badge don't work. In my server side code I have:

```
$messageBody['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'sound' => 'default','badge' => 2);
```

This the iOS code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    //print(error)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    print(deviceToken)

}


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotificationuserInfo userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil))

    initLocationManager()

    return true

}
```

Why are sound and badge not working?

Comment: it seems ok (this is server-side code, I think), what about the ios client side code?

Comment: Yes, this is a php code of my server api, this code send to APNs, this array is used by send to apple

Comment: Where is your IOS code?

Comment: Sorry, I edit the post and add iOS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php code looks alright. In the app, have you registered for pushnotifications? Also try to uninstall the app and then reinstall it and accept sounds and badges for the app.

EDIT: Also enable sounds and badges in your settings for your app.

EDIT 2: Try this: do: `let types:UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]` and then `application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil))` You have to register the app for Alert, Sound and Badges but you only had registered for Alert.

Comment: I've done this, I uninstall the app, accept the sounds and badges, but dont worked

Comment: Where enable sounds and badges? Is it not automatic?

Comment: @AlexandreC.doCarmo I see, you register the App only for alerts and not for Sound and badges...

Comment: @AlexandreC.doCarmo do: `let types:UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]` and then `application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil))`

Comment: @AlexandreC.doCarmo No problem